# How to remove post parameters on temporary redirect (HTTP 307)?

Tags: java, http, redirect, header, response

I have a problem with redirecting requests. I have an incoming [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) for `http://foo.com/bar?A=b`. I redirect it with HTTP 307 to `http://hockily.com/dockily?C=d&E=f`.

But at hockily.com , I have both the A, C and E. A is on GET parameters, C and E are on POST parameters. I need to remove the A. I should not send it. How can I do that?

I'm using Java's `Response` for a return like

```
return Response.temporaryRedirect(
    URI.create((String) s.get("redirectString"))
).build();
```

Please feel free to comment for extra information that I couldn't think of to provide.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use 303 instead of 307

Comment: is it ? i tried 301 10 seoconds ago. worked now. ill see 303 too

Comment: 307 indicates that the client should repeat the request - including POST data - to the new `Location:`. 303 indicates that the new request should be a GET request, and POST data will be dropped. 301 is a permanent redirect and I doubt it is what you want. 302 will most likely have the desired effect, but the "correct" way to do what you want is 303

Comment: i see then . what about 301 ? it solved my problem but should i still try 303 ? , thats why im curious about the subtleties

Comment: The best thing I can recommend is for you to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) and (if you can manage it without wanting to kill yourself) [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3).

Comment: i just read that before your comment XD the first sentence in wiki is pretty directive! can you post your answer please? so i can accept and close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct HTTP status code for redirecting a client to GET from a new URI after a POST request is 303. You should use the `seeOther()` method instead.

Comment: Works for me. Java is not my regular haunt, I was just perusing the [http] tag :-)

Comment: trying to help people with all detail i can give :) wasted my hours on temporary redirect

Comment: It's a subtle but important difference, made even more difficult by the fact that most clients treat 302 as if it were 303 when this is not RFC-compliant behaviour. It just takes a bit of getting used to - but at least you'll never do it again ;-)

Comment: actually its been such an efficient waste for me . been reading almost every redirection Code and how it should be in RFC and how it's adopted in industry.ive read 303 and 307 were added because of the misuse of 302. interesting